# Ctr-Z & PyDev Package explorer

Tags: pydev

More a bug/feature warning/report:

If Ctrl-Z is pressed while the PyDev Package explorer has focus, it (for example) removes recently added and edited copies of source files. No redo is possible. Just the three newest versions of a file with a day of work in them.

Very annoying and hard to sell to my customer.

I don't have time to (figure out how to) file a bug report etc. But if any wants to carry the ball ...

Anyway, cheers too all and be careful.

Lars

In answer to Fabio's question:

Just tested: If i copy a file within a project (drag/ctrl_c, ctrl_v), change the file (or not, but this is more bothering), save it, click on navigation pane and ctrl_z, the file is removed. It can be restored from 'restore from local history'.

If i create a new file and ctrl_z nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Humm... actually, you can redo 'manually' by right clicking the folder containing the files and choosing 'restore from local history'.

Now, this doesn't happen to me with PyDev installed, so, I believe it's the work of some other plugin... which other plugins you have installed? (I remember having a similar issue with subversive, not sure if it was fixed, but it may be some other plugin too...)

Comment: By now i have reinstalled eclipse and cannot remember what else i had installed, sorry.

Comment: So, this no longer happens to you?

Comment: If i do create new pydev file in project -> click on editor -> click on navigation pane -> cltr_z) nothing happens.

Comment: actually the same behaviour happpens, see the comments added to the question